# OpenLayers Vector Style change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, openlayers, geoserver

When I click on button on map I would like to change vector style (fillColor). I tried this with no luck.

```
var map;
var layer, wms;

function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {
        layers: 'basic'
    });
    var myStyle = {
        fill: true,
        fillColor: "#ff0000"
    };
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        style: myStyle,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "tasmania_roads",
            featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
        })
    });

    map.addLayers([wms, layer]);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(146.7, -41.8), 6);

        var panel_type2 = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
        displayClass: 'Panel2'
    });
    map.addControl(panel_type2);

    var redraw = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
        displayClass: 'first',
        trigger: function () {
            layer.destroyFeatures();
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            var myStyle = {
                fill: true,
                fillColor: "#DFDFFF"
            };
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                style: myStyle,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                })
            });

            map.addLayers([layer]);
        }
    });
    panel_type2.addControls([redraw]);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/WzbVB/)**

When I click on button I am trying to redraw vector layer with new style. But its not working. Could someone brief me why its not changing fillcolor and How can I change?

Help Would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that what is being returned from the wfs request is just lines, there are no polygons, so your fillStyle is being ignored, as there is nothing to apply it to. I have updated your fiddle and put a strokeColor attribute in your stylemap, and now it works as expected:

```
var myStyle1 = {
      fill: true,
      fillColor: "#DFDFFF",
      strokeColor: "#FF0000"
};
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WzbVB/1/)

Comment: Ah. Thats Awesome Bro. Didn't noticed strokeColor. Thanks. +1

Comment: You are welcome, bro. Sometimes a 2nd pair of eyes really helps.

Comment: Could you please join  in this chat room . I have few doubts regarding maps APIs. If you could help me to sort it out it will be really helpful to me.http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55658/google-maps-api-vs-arcgis-javascript-maps-api